# Customizing the Log a call Task Page

Tags: visualforce, tasks

How to make Type, Call Disposition and Comments fields mandatory for tasks with status completed vs tasks with status not started.

I know it can be done by having validation rules, but that won't show the thick red lines beside the field.

Do I need to write custom VF page to achieve this? It looks like a lot of work.

Basically we want to have mandatory fields different for Task with status completed vs Tasks with status Not started.

Below is the screen, I am referring to:

[image]

Comment: You are correct. It would require custom work / validation rules

Comment: Thanks @Eric. I just started writing custom VF page..hopefully I can achieve this easily.